# How to retrieve all "audience" users of an interactive audio streaming channel

Tags: agora.io

I am using `AgoraWebSDK-NG` to do a `Web` implementation.

My application uses interactive audio streaming. Video is not required.

I want to know how to retrieve all users who are part of the "audience" of a channel (and not "hosts"). I want to display such "audience" users in the UI.

Unfortunately I cannot find any method to be able to do so here https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#getlisteners

Please let me know how this would be possible. An example would be great. If it is not possible, then just let me know that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible at the moment with the NG SDK. To achieve this right now, you can use the [Agora RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/product_rtm?platform=All%20Platforms).

You can [create an RTM channel](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmclient.html#createchannel) with the same name as the RTC channel. Then you can use the [RTM's channel events](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/interfaces/rtmevents.rtmchannelevents.html) to know when an audience member joins or leaves.